# PostgreSQL optimizing query - maybee nested loop is the problem

Tags: postgresql, optimization, nested-loops

I have this very slow query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT et.id
FROM elementtype et
where et.id = any
  (SELECT elementtypeid
   FROM
     (SELECT ic.elementtypeid
      FROM
        (SELECT categoryid
         FROM issue
         WHERE clientid = '833e1f2f-ff44-4aca-bd12-0e4f67969a11'
           AND deleteddate IS NULL
         GROUP BY categoryid) i
      JOIN issuecategory ic ON ic.id = i.categoryid
      UNION SELECT tc.elementtypeid
      FROM
        (SELECT categoryid
         FROM task
         WHERE clientid = '833e1f2f-ff44-4aca-bd12-0e4f67969a11'
           AND deleteddate IS NULL
         GROUP BY categoryid) t
      JOIN taskcategory tc ON tc.id = t.categoryid) icc)
```

I have tried to change the ANY operator with IN, made an join instead of IN (in line 3 of the query) but it is still very slow, when the result is not cached.

I think it might be the nested loop making the problem - but I dont know if I can get rid of it - and why et only

[image]

As you can see, I use a couple of indexes _idx an of course primary keys on every table.

the elementtype table has ~6000 rows
the issue sub-query with these conditions (not group by) returns ~33000 rows
the task sub-query with these conditions (not group by) returns ~148000 rows

Is there any way to optimize the query?

EDIT:
As requested by @a_horse_with_no_name I add a query plan using the command he/she surgested. The best way to post it in here, is is using an image, I think:

```
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=473976.82..474453.63 rows=4453 width=16) (actual time=69897.728..69897.737 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=61346 read=19651
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=473976.82..474442.49 rows=4453 width=16) (actual time=69897.724..69897.731 rows=1 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (et.id = ic.elementtypeid)
        Buffers: shared hit=61346 read=19651
        ->  Index Only Scan using elementtype_pkey on elementtype et  (cost=0.28..384.47 rows=5879 width=16) (actual time=0.021..32.618 rows=1784 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 1784
              Buffers: shared hit=1699 read=54
        ->  Sort  (cost=473976.54..473987.67 rows=4453 width=16) (actual time=69863.461..69863.464 rows=1 loops=1)
              Sort Key: ic.elementtypeid
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              Buffers: shared hit=59647 read=19597
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=473617.61..473662.14 rows=4453 width=16) (actual time=69863.432..69863.436 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Group Key: ic.elementtypeid
                    Buffers: shared hit=59647 read=19597
                    ->  Append  (cost=107927.43..473606.48 rows=4453 width=16) (actual time=114.259..69863.317 rows=55 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=59647 read=19597
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=107927.43..109170.43 rows=3625 width=16) (actual time=114.257..208.716 rows=46 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (ic.id = issue.categoryid)
                                Buffers: shared hit=15431
                                ->  Seq Scan on issuecategory ic  (cost=0.00..1100.36 rows=54336 width=32) (actual time=0.011..47.327 rows=54336 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=557
                                ->  Hash  (cost=107882.12..107882.12 rows=3625 width=16) (actual time=113.850..113.850 rows=46 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 35kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=14874
                                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=107809.62..107845.87 rows=3625 width=16) (actual time=113.738..113.795 rows=46 loops=1)
                                            Group Key: issue.categoryid
                                            Buffers: shared hit=14874
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on issue  (cost=1801.41..107730.88 rows=31493 width=16) (actual time=7.279..81.266 rows=33670 loops=1)
                                                  Recheck Cond: (clientid = '833e1f2f-ff44-4aca-bd12-0e4f67969a11'::uuid)
                                                  Filter: (deleteddate IS NULL)
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 1362
                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=14636
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=14874
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on issue_clientid_ix  (cost=0.00..1793.54 rows=32681 width=0) (actual time=5.165..5.166 rows=35064 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (clientid = '833e1f2f-ff44-4aca-bd12-0e4f67969a11'::uuid)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=238
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=360635.19..364391.52 rows=828 width=16) (actual time=69603.779..69654.505 rows=9 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=44216 read=19597
                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=360634.78..360643.06 rows=828 width=16) (actual time=69592.635..69592.657 rows=9 loops=1)
                                      Group Key: task.categoryid
                                      Buffers: shared hit=44198 read=19579
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on task  (cost=3438.67..360280.46 rows=141728 width=16) (actual time=33.283..69416.182 rows=147931 loops=1)
                                            Recheck Cond: (clientid = '833e1f2f-ff44-4aca-bd12-0e4f67969a11'::uuid)
                                            Filter: (deleteddate IS NULL)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 2329
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=63193
                                            Buffers: shared hit=44198 read=19579
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on task_clientid_ix  (cost=0.00..3403.24 rows=148091 width=0) (actual time=20.865..20.866 rows=150975 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (clientid = '833e1f2f-ff44-4aca-bd12-0e4f67969a11'::uuid)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=584
                                ->  Index Scan using taskcategory_pkey on taskcategory tc  (cost=0.42..4.52 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6.865..6.865 rows=1 loops=9)
                                      Index Cond: (id = task.categoryid)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=18 read=18
Planning time: 1.173 ms
Execution time: 69899.380 ms
```

EDIT2:

- issuecategory has index on id, clintid, elementypeid
- issue has index on clientid, deleteddate and categoryid
- taskcategory has index on id, clientid, elementtypeid,
- task has index on clientid, id, deleteddate, categoryid

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - no screenshots or graphical plans (they just hide too many details). Make sure you preserve the indention of the plan: paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - hope you can use it

Comment: What is 'very slow'? Is 224ms 'very slow' or is that fast because being the 2nd time you ran it everything is already in memory?

Comment: Your query seems pretty convoluted. As a first step I would suggest simplifying it. I think it could be stripped down to an `INNER JOIN` between `elementtype` and `issuecategory` and a `WHERE` clause with `ic.id IN (SELECT id FROM issue WHERE ... UNION ALL SELECT id FROM task WHERE...)`.

Comment: @jjanes : The first one was cached

Comment: Please put the query plan in text form, or even better put it on https://explain.depesz.com/ that will format it nicely with readable timings.

Comment: Please show table descriptions (psql command \d table) for taskcategory and issuecategory, I'd like to see what indices exist on these tables. Also, what is the count of distinct categoryid? Is there a categories table with categoryid as primary key? Also would like to see table descriptions with indices for issues and tasks.

Comment: @bobflux : here you go. Thanks for the depesz.com link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the bitmap heap scans.  They seem to be jumping to a lot of different parts of the disk to fetch the data they need.

The best solution is probably to create indexes on `(clientid, categoryid, deleteddate)` on each table, or maybe `(clientid, categoryid) where deleteddate is null`.  This will allow those bitmap heap scans to be replaced with index-only scans (assuming your tables are vacuumed well enough).

Other approaches would be to CLUSTER the tables so that rows with the same clientid are physically grouped together, or increase effective_io_concurrency so more IO can be done at the same time (assuming your storage system has multiple spindles in RAID/JBOD, or whatever the SSD equivalent to that is).

Comment: Yes. I was asking him how many category ids there were in total because the number the query gets is pretty small. So instead of reading a gorillion rows to get 500 distinct ids from the huge table, it would probably be much faster to start from category ids from the category table, do an EXISTS() to check if each id has a row in the huge table that checks out, and then done.